# Why does Marco Pierre White use a spatula instead of a Soup Ladle?

Tags: cookware, utensils

https://youtu.be/yeg67jnZozU

I usually use a soup ladle when making soup. I see Marco using a spatula when making his soup in the linked video. Why is that?

I get that plastic utensils are preferred when using non stick cookware so not to scratch the coating, but a spatula seems odd when dealing with nearly half a gallon of soup.

Comment: What would you do with the ladle that you couldn’t do with a spatula?

Answer (score 19):

I'd use a wooden spatula rather than one of those over-flexible plastic ones, but…
a soup ladle is for *serving* soup. It's completely the wrong implement for *making* it.

You can't stir properly, making sure nothing is sticking to the bottom or round the edges whilst frying/sautéing or even later whilst simmering. You can't scrape round the pan sides, or pick up a knob of butter…  It's just too clumsy at that point in the process.

Comment: With thicker soups, being able to clear the bottom while simmering is vital, especially in big batches.  That's enough reason alone, but a reasonably stiff spatula will stir the bulk at least as well as a ladle.  I was going to say the same as you but forgot to finish my post, so have my vote instead.

Comment: In that recipe in particular, you really want to be able to turn over the veg as it's softening, to ensure even heating.  A flat thing does that better than anything else.  That's a reason to prefer a spatula over a wooden spoon, let alone a ladle.

Comment: Agree on the wooden spoon. Can't think of anything they might ever be actually useful for. My girlfriend swears by them. I swear *at* them. Pointless lumps of wood. Spatulas FTW, every time ;)

Comment: Now if only I could get spatulas (I've got some nice wooden ones) as long as some of my spoons, to reach the bottom of a stock pot full of soup.

Comment: @ChrisH I’ve seen ones that approaching the size of small boat paddles at both restaurant supply stores and at Hispanic grocery stores.  (You want one that has a good section of huge pots, like you’re cooking for 20+ people, not just a small section with tortilla presses and citrus squeezers).  You can also get them on Amazon (look for Cajun or gumbo mentioned, like https://www.amazon.com//dp/B0BNL27F7P/

Comment: @Joe that suggests somewhere I've been planning to go for a while (the retail shop for a wholesaler, that's mainly an Indian supermarket but with some catering supplies). Not that it's really a big deal, I don't cook that much bulk often, but coincidentally did 5 litres last week.